# If you have two bachelor's degree in related fields, can you mention in your CV only the latest of the two?

Tags: graduate-school, cv

I obtained my bachelor's degree from a third tier school before completing my second bachelor's degree and a master's degree at more reputable schools. I was wondering if it is acceptable to omit my first bachelor's degree from my CV.

Comment: Include all of your education.

Comment: CV for what? For graduate admissions, you will likely have to list (and supply transcripts from) _all_ schools you've attended anyway.

Comment: Why would you want to leave it out?

Answer (score 3):

I think it would make for an awkward line of questioning at an interview when they inevitably ask what you did during those years and you reply that you completed a Bachelors degree but didn't feel it was good enough to include it.

Worst case scenario: your interviewer went to that institution and you've just shot yourself in the foot.

Always include your full educational and work experience as it makes for easy nitpicking at an interview that is easily avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Withholding the information would be acceptable to most people, but it may expose a large gap in your education/employment track record. You may be asked about what you did during these years.