# Can I not mention courses taken on my graduate school application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application

This question is a followup to my previous question on Academia SE: [How can I explain poor grades on courses taken after obtaining my undergraduate degree?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/178544/how-can-i-explain-poor-grades-on-courses-taken-after-obtaining-my-undergraduate)

A commenter suggested that I `try hiding that educational history from your applications`.

Can I simply not mention schools that I've taken courses in that I don't want to report? The application does ask for transcripts from all colleges received.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/93696/if-you-have-two-bachelors-degree-in-related-fields-can-you-mention-in-your-cv

Comment: It's easy to catch people who do this.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Actually, I suspect that, in GDPR jurisdictions, it might be really rather difficult to catch people who do this.

Comment: BTW, the (now-deleted) comment you refer to is a good example of one reason why we don't allow answers in the comments -- they let people post dangerous and unethical advice without giving the community a chance to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been enrolled in a degree program you will be expected to provide transcripts for all such. It is a form of fraud, and thus discouraged, to try to hide this.

However, if you take the occasional course as a "non-matriculated" student there is no real need to list them. So, in particular, you needn't list online courses offered by commercial entities. But even the occasional night course that isn't part of a degree you are enrolled in can be omitted.

But, don't try to finesse it. Academic misconduct can be treated as a serious issue. Your previous question suggests you were a masters degree student, so you are ethically bound to list it.